# Why is there a gray area at the top of my NavigationView

Tags: android

I create a testing app to learn how to build a slide menu. Now I get a strange problem.

[image: Screen shot]

Why is there a gray area at the top of the `NavigationView`? How to remove it?

Here is my code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="tw.com.phd.slidemenutest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="tw.com.phd.slidemenutest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_menu, R.string.close_menu);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**drawer_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" your DrawerLayout

Comment: Please post your `@layout/drawer_header`

Comment: Have you tried removing `app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"` ?

Answer (score 3):

The same issue was faced by me I search a lot , finally got one solution.
Try this solution, this might work for you as it worked for me too.

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)view. findViewById(R.id.nav_view_completed);
    if (navigationView != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        navigationView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                return insets;
            }
        });
    }
```

Let me know further if still not work.

Comment: Indeed I was changing window insets in a different helper class and this helped relieve this mysterious gray bar issue.  Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.